# Manually order a Jekyll collection

Tags: html, yaml, jekyll, github-pages

As mentioned in the Jekyll docs [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#manually-ordering-documents), I have the following in my `_config.yml` as:

```
collections:
  sections:
    order:
      - introduction.md
      - battery-state.md
      - vibe.md
      - references.md
```

To render the content of each file within the HTML, I have the following:

```
{% for section in site.sections %}
  {{ section.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, the content order is not presented as what I defined in the config file. How do I display the content in the order I defined in the config file?

Comment: It is a Jekyll 4.0 feature. Ensure that you're using the latest version of jekyll..

Comment: @ashmaroli Looks like Github Pages Jekyll is currently v3.8.5 https://pages.github.com/versions/ which is the version I'm using. Hopefully GitHub will update to the latest version soon.

Comment: There an issue on GitHub to support v4.0 for GitHub Pages https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually ordering documents in a collection was introduced in Jekyll 4.0
To use this feature, make sure that you're using Jekyll 4.0

For a site deployed on GitHub Pages, that would mean having to build the site outside GitHub Pages environment and upload the contents of the *destination directory* (`_site`).

Answer (score 2):

You can also choose to add the sections to the front matter of the page. This is useful when you are not using Jekyll v4 or you want the user to be able to edit the order in CloudCannon, Netlify CMS, Forestry or another CMS with front matter editor.

```
sections:
  - introduction
  - battery-state
  - vibe
  - references
```

And the use a layout like this:

```
{% for s in page.sections %}
    {% for section in site.sections %}
        {% if s == section.slug %}
             ...
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is a good temporary solution until v4.0 is available on GitHub Pages. Thank you for the suggestion.